# Disable MySQL secure_auth client option with ZeosLib

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-7, zeos

I'm trying to connect to a remote MySQL server and i get this exception error:

*Connection using old (pre-4.1.1) authentication protocol refused (client option 'secure_auth' enabled)*

I'm tried to disable the "secure_auth" option by adding the string "MYSQL_SECURE_AUTH=false" to the TZConnection properties, but i get the same error.

I'm using ZeosLib 7.0.4 and Delphi 7. The server has MySQL 5.0.95

Comment: The latest zeoslib is 7.1.2. But the problem is likely that you've specified an old MySQL version in the Connection component.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I use mysql-5 as protocol in the TZconnection object. If I try to connect using the Mysql Workbench I get the same error, but I can disable the "secure-auth" option there. I've updated Zeos to 7.1.2-stable but still got the connection error.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved!
The server is MySQL 5.0.95 (secure_auth disabled) and I was using libmysql.dll 5.6.11 (secure_auth enabled by default). Placing the libmysql.dll 5.0 in the app folder solved it.
I don't understand yet why i can't change the "MYSQL_SECURE_AUTH" at TZConnection.properties.